# Getting spam registration and contact form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Recently I have been getting too much spam registration and contact form submission with the same user named Bradley Bradley with no extra information. I have put google recaptcha and honeypots as well but still no help.

Comment: What would you like us to do about it?

Comment: Was wondering, if there is a better way of doing this. I am getting spam with the same name Bradley Bradley.

Comment: Not scalable and could limit legitimate submissions from someone actually named Bradley Bradley....but I guess you could put some logic into the jQuery to toss the registration out and exit if the name matches Bradley Bradley?

Comment: Jonathan Bowman  That sounds good. Can you please help me with the script that i need to put to avoid someone named Bradley Bradley.

Comment: @sonu769, if you wanna help with code, please post what you've already have (html form, plugins, scripts, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Use Server side validation like check whether Username is already exist in the table or check email existance etc. & write the code which will not allow user to submit the data.You can use PHP here.